# SOAPUI - Parse different JSON Response objects to fetch the same child node values using Groovy Scripting

Tags: json, rest, groovy, soapui

I'm automating REST API's using SOAPUI. I've 2 different resources and below are the Response JSON formats.
The root element varies but the status block remains same for both the response jsons. After the Rest API POST call, I've a Groovy script in place to validate the response (if "code" == "00")

Goal: Using Groovy Script, I've to Parse through the JSON and retreive the "code" node value irrespective of the root element.

**Response(JSON) Formats**:

```
{
    "resouurce_1_response":
    {
        "status":
        {
            "code": "00"
        }
    }
}

{
    "resource_2_response":
    {
        "status":
        {
            "code": "00"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way of doing it would be:

```
def json1 = '{ "resouurce_1_response": { "status": { "code": "00" } } }'
def json2 = '{ "resource_2_response": { "status": { "code": "00" } } }'

import groovy.json.*

def slurper = new JsonSlurper()

assert slurper.parseText(json1).find().value.status.code == '00'
assert slurper.parseText(json2).find().value.status.code == '00'
```

Of course, if your actual Json is more complex than you show, you might need to do something different (recursively walk the map?)

Comment: That Works. Thank you Yates for your time and easy solution.

Comment: Glad to help!  Good luck, and have fun! :-)  (ps:  you can accept the answer, by ticking the box on the left)